# how to add urls to Flash white list in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I develop small crawler with puppeteer in Node.js.
the target site has Flash contents, so I want to enable Flash in puppeteer.

by default, puppeteer is unable to use Flash and white list of permitted sites is empty.
I know how to enable Flash in puppeteer, but I don't know how to set white list.

How to do that?
Is there flag like this?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            '--ppapi-flash-path = {FLASH_PATH}',
            '--white-url = {TARGET_URL}'
        ]
    });
```

Or, is it only way to simply manipulate DOM in setting page in browser (ex.chrome://settings/content/flash)?

Comment: If you don't get a response here, try posting in one of the other [alternative](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#user-content-q-i-have-more-questions-where-do-i-ask) forums they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself.
I can't find the flag of Flash white list and manipulate DOM of chrome's setting page is too tiring for me, but I got useful some params.

**1. 'userDataDir: {PROFILE_FILE}'**

First, manually launch chrome or chromium, and add url to the list.
Then, set PROFILE_FILE as its user data path.

**2. executablePath: '{PATH_TO_CHROME}'**

Basically, run on chrome but not chromium, we can use Flash and HLS and etc. by default.
Set manually white list, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering I found a Preferences file configuration that whitelists all flash content by default.

I've made [a small puppeteer wrapper](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra) to make using this very easy: `puppeteer.setExtra({allowFlash: true})`

```js
{
  "profile": {
    "content_settings": {
      "exceptions": {
        "flash_data": {
          "*,*": {
            "setting": {
              "flashPreviouslyChanged": true
            }
          }
        },
        "permission_autoblocking_data": {
          "*,*": {
            "setting": {
              "Flash": {
                "dismiss_count": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "plugins": {
          "*,*": {
            "per_resource": {
              "adobe-flash-player": 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "pref_version": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @endzeit, thanks for writing that down. I've tried using your puppeteer wrapper but it seems to have issues with newer versions of Chrome (75.0.3770.100) - it is indeed detectable, but is blocked by default and requires manual settings change and then manual clicking to enable on particular page. Am I missing something? Perhaps you have some minor tips?