# Puppeteer-extra allow flash support

Tags: puppeteer

I need puppeteer (not in headless mode) to open a page and have flash enabled from the get go.
Meaning no manual downloading or clicking to run flash.

So far i've added puppeteer-extra and its flash plugin as was used in a prior question:

[Allowing to run Flash on all sites in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005040/allowing-to-run-flash-on-all-sites-in-puppeteer)

My chrome version is 75.0.3770.142 and my puppeteer dependencies are:

```
* "puppeteer": "^1.19.0",
* "puppeteer-core": "^1.19.0",
* "puppeteer-extra": "^2.1.3",
* "puppeteer-extra-plugin-flash": "^2.1.3",
* "puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-data-dir": "^2.1.2",
* "puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences": "^2.1.2",
```

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import PuppeteerCore from 'puppeteer-core';
import PuppeteerExtra from 'puppeteer-extra';
import PuppeteerFlash from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-flash';
PuppeteerExtra.use(PuppeteerFlash());

(async () => {
  const browser = await PuppeteerExtra.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
    args: [
      '--window-size=800,600',
      '--enable-webgl',
      '--enable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  await page.goto('http://ultrasounds.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
})();
```

I expected the above code to open the page, download the necessary flash and run the flash content when done.

As it is though, it does the download but still requires a user to click enable flash to make the content run.

I'm wondering if anyone could please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong in the above code, if I've misunderstood something or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the localPath chrome app, you needn't the puppeteer-extra-plugin-flash.

```html
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://v.qq.com/iframe/preview.html?width=500&amp;height=375&amp;auto=0&amp;vid=a30198lw6j2');
  const dimensions = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
      src: document.getElementById('tenvideo_video_player_0').getAttribute('src'),
    };
  });

  console.log('Dimensions:', dimensions);

  await browser.close();

})();
```